# Flutter Hide Underline of Searchable Dropdown button

Tags: flutter, dropdown

How can I remove the underline from Searchable Drop down Button , I have tried various combinations of options with Input Decoration couldn't find any way.

```
child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
    child: SearchableDropdown.single(
      items: this.searchableItems,
      value: this._selectSubordinate,
      hint: "Subordinate",
      searchHint: "Enter yoursubordinate name or Business code",
      onChanged: (value) {
        setState(() {
          this._selectSubordinate = value;
        });
      },
      isExpanded: true,
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

used `underline` properties :)

```dart
SearchableDropdown.single(
      underline: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
      ),
      items: _serviceItems,
      value: selectedServiceVal,
      onChanged: (value) => setState(() {
        selectedServiceVal = value;
        _subjectTextController.text =
            '${selectedServiceVal ?? ''} - ${selectedCustomerVal ?? ''}';
      }),
      isExpanded: true,
    );
```

cf. flutter searchable dropdown version
https://pub.dev/packages/searchable_dropdown

```
# searchable dropdown
  searchable_dropdown: ^1.1.3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
underline: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(child: Container()),
```